# Считывать построчно файл и заодно считать количество значений

Tags: python

Есть файл, к примеру file.txt. В нём есть числа 1 и 2. К примеру, в таком порядке:

```
1
1
1
2
2
1
2
2
1
2
1
2
2
```

Надо чтобы файл посчитал 1 и 2 и, к примеру, в output выводилось бы:

```
One number:6
Two number:7
```

Я новичок в Python и может чего-нибудь не знаю. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём конкретно? Или вам код написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Код:*

```py
count1 = 0 
count2 = 0

with open('file.txt') as f:
    row = True

    while row:
        row = f.readline().rstrip()

        if row == '1':
            count1 += 1
        elif row == '2':
            count2 += 1

print(f'One number:{count1}\n'
      f'Two number:{count2}')
```

*stdout:*

```html
One number:6
Two number:7
```

Данный код построчно читает файл, на каждой итерации инкрементируя нужный счётчик.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    myList = f.read().split()

print("One number:{} \nTwo number:{}".format(myList.count('1'), myList.count('2')))
```

One number:6

Two number:7